# Shorthand for: return if not nil

Tags: ruby

I use variable caching to cut down on execution time like so:

```
def some_method
  return @var if @var
  [some other code that gets executed only once]
end
```

Is there a shorthand for `return @var if @var` ? If its a single line method I use:

```
@var ||= [some more code]
```

Can something similar (short) be done with multiline methods?

Comment: Is it necessary to recalculate it if `@var` is not `nil` but is not `present?`?

Comment: No, I doesn't matter if it is nil or nor present.

Comment: Then your `present?` is redundant and misleading.

Comment: Thank you for the comment; adjusted the question accordingly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use this:

```
@var ||= begin
   # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

is it necessary for that to happen inside `some_method` ?

If not, I would think of doing

```
def some_method_wrapper
  @var || some_method
end
```

that way you can keep `some_method` clean.